# Javascript Obfuscation error- get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, obfuscation

I'm making a `chrome extension` and i'm currently trying to obfuscate one of my scripts so users cannot view the source.

For the purpose of the question, say I have this simple `get` request:

```
$.get(
    "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=13416513",
    function (data){
        alert($(data).find(".UserBlurb").html());
    }
);
```

If you were to run that in console on [roblox.com](http://roblox.com), you would receive an alert of the user's description. Now, if I run this code in the `background page` of my extension, I will receive the same result (The user's description). But I want to obfuscate this code in the `background page`.

Running the obfuscated code in the background page wasn't working BUT if you ran the obfuscated code in console at [roblox.com](http://roblox.com), it works. This has me completely confused.

This is the obfuscator I was using- [www.atasoyweb.net/Javascript_Encrypter](http://www.atasoyweb.net/Javascript_Encrypter/javascript_encrypter_eng.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encrypter uses `eval` which is not allowed in chrome extensions. (Though you can [get around it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval))

Related: Don't even bother obfuscating your scripts. All encrypting methods can be "decrypted" (if it couldn't then how does your code run?)

Comment: Do you know of any encrypter that dont use this?

Comment: @Alex - Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript ;)